# How can I configure the Windows Show Desktop button to not hide/ignore certain applications?

Tags: windows-11, microsoft

I use Windows sticky notes to take notes, such as todos, quick notes, etc. I keep these open on the desktop to view quickly, but when I have several other applications open in full screen, it is a hassle to minimize five or six applications to see my notes. Instead I use the Show Desktop button in the bottom right corner, however this button also minimizes my notes and I have to reopen them to read them. How can I reconfigure the Show Desktop to minimize all of my applications except for the Sticky Notes application?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's article
[Get started with Sticky Notes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-started-with-sticky-notes-86b36182-fdf5-4f9b-af7a-2846f83263f5)
has this note:

> You cannot currently have Sticky Notes stay on top of other applications. But you can pin Sticky Notes to the Windows taskbar to see your list of notes instantly or to create a new note quickly. Right-click the Sticky Notes icon in the taskbar, and then click Pin to taskbar.

Pinning to the taskbar is at least a method for fast access to your notes.

I use
[Stickies](https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/stickies/)
instead of the Windows sticky notes.
It has an "On top" setting that keeps it on top of even full-screen
windows, and it will also stay visible after Show Desktop is clicked.

These are two very different application, but there exist quite a few
other free
[to-do list applications](https://alternativeto.net/software/stickies/?license=free&platform=windows)
for Windows that might better suite your work-style.

Comment: Stickes works really well, thank you!